# How to add the log in the reactive programming

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

```html
public ObjectNode addLabelColorCodes(ObjectNode objectNode) {
        Map<String, String> lablesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
       if (!AList.isEmpty()) {
                String joinedIds = StringUtils.join(AList, ",");
                LOGGER.info("join Ids are {}", joinedIds);

               return Client.getLabelsById(joinedIds).doOnNext(response -> LOGGER.info("Labesl Response List:{}", response))
                       .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getObjects())
                        .doOnNext(Response -> {
                           objectNode.with("display").put(lablesMap.get(Response.getId()),Response.getLabel());
                       })
                        .then(Mono.just(objectNode))
                        .doOnNext(modified -> LOGGER.info("After Adding ObjectNode :{}", modified))
                        .onErrorReturn(objectNode)
                       .block();
            }
        }
        LOGGER.info("After Adding ObjectNode :{}", objectNode);
        return  objectNode;
    }
```

How to add the logging for the objectNode on error return **.onErrorReturn(objectNode)**

Comment: Try using `.onErrorResume` instead of `onErrorReturn`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `.doOnError()` operator to perform operations that do not impact the current stream. ie

```
                           .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getObjects())
                            .doOnNext(Response -> {
                               objectNode.with("display").put(lablesMap.get(Response.getId()),Response.getLabel());
                           })
                           .doOnError(throwable -> LOGGER.warn("Error encountered", ))
```

One further note. Try to keep immutability in mind when doing reactive programming. Instead of mutating the ObjectNode object inside a doOnNext it would be preferable to use a map/flatmap where you transform the Response Object into a new ObjectNode.